# custom pattern to filter strings when using telegraf inputs.logparser.grok

Tags: go, devops, influxdb, logparser, telegraf

I'm trying filter for particular words in a log file using regex, the goal is that any log line that matches the regex in custom_pattern will go into influxdb, log lines that do not match willbe ignored. When I tested the regex it works, even in golang playground (https://play.golang.org/p/_apzOVwwgl2). But when I use it in the telegraf conf file as it is below, it doesn't work, there's no input into influxdb. Is there something I'm missing that should added to the configuration?

I've tested the regex on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and https://play.golang.org/p/_apzOVwwgl2 it works but not in the  custom_patterns under [inputs.logparser.grok].

Here is my grok config

```
[[inputs.logparser]]
   files = ["/var/log/test1"]
   from_beginning = true

   [inputs.logparser.grok]
      patterns = ["%{FAIL_LOG}"]
      custom_patterns = '''FAIL_LOG ^.*?\b(multipathd?)\b.*?\b(failed|failing|(remaining active paths))\b.*?$'''
```

The pattern is supposed to match first 2 log lines like below and ignore the third line.

```
Oct 29 03:29:03 dc-as-5p multipath: checker failed interface 8:0 in map 150gb
Oct 29 03:29:03 dc-as-5p multipathd: checker failing interface 8:0 in map 150gb
Oct 29 03:26:03 dc-as-5p link: checker down remaining active paths interface 8:0 in map 150gb
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I changed the pattern to ```%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME} (?<prog>multipathd?): (?<message>(.*(failed|failing|(remaining active paths)).*))``` I was still able to match the first 2 log lines as expected, without matching the third log line. However, when I use this pattern inside inputs.logparser.grok, it still did not work, no input written to influxdb. Help PLEASE!

Answer (score 1):

I summarised how I got custom log parsing in Telegraf/GROK to work in the following post: [Custom log parsing with Telegraf/Tail Plugin/GROK](https://community.influxdata.com/t/custom-log-parsing-with-latest-tail-plugin-grok-and-influxdb-configuration-for-grafana/14986?u=eclements). Maybe it helps you or others debug similar problems.

Maybe interessting for others reading this in 2020, that Telegraf's logparser is now replaced by the [Tail plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/tail). Example in my post above.

PS: My approach for your problem would be to not use regex at all, but to define three different patterns for each of the lines. This of course will only work if you have a low number of possible log errors/lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you run telegraf with the `--debug` flag, you will see that it is having an issue parsing the logs.

```
$ telegraf --debug --config ./telegraf.conf
...
2019-11-17T05:01:07Z D! Grok no match found for: "Oct 29 03:29:03 dc-as-5p multipath: checker failed interface 8:0 in map 150gb"
2019-11-17T05:01:07Z D! Grok no match found for: "Oct 29 03:29:03 dc-as-5p multipathd: checker failing interface 8:0 in map 150gb value=3"
2019-11-17T05:01:07Z D! Grok no match found for: "Oct 29 03:26:03 dc-as-5p link: checker down remaining active paths interface 8:0 in map 150gb"
```

This error message is misleading because, as your testing has shown, your regex pattern is correct.  The real issue is that you have not included a value to be logged in your regex.

A version of your regex to store the error message and timestamp might be:

```
    custom_patterns = '''FAIL_LOG %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}.*(multipath).?: %{GREEDYDATA:message:string}'''
```

The value pattern can be found between `${}`.  Additional premade patterns can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns).  This will eliminate the first two errors above.  The results of these can be seen using the `--test` flag.

```
$telegraf --test --config ./telegraf.conf
...
> logparser,host=pop-os,path=./test1 message="checker failed interface 8:0 in map 150gb",timestamp="Oct 29 03:29:03 " 1573968174161853621
```

For some reason the `--test` flag did not always output the results.  I would have to run the command multiple times before getting the above output.